# App Icon appearing small in Xcode Deployment Info

Tags: xcode, icons, size

I'm running out of hair to pull.  I created two icons:

icon@2x.png (114x114)
icon.png (57x57)

For some reason they appear half sized, however.  See this screenshot:

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxSFZAq0OUFGbXFWbWNTVlo3RHc

I'm 100% confident my icon sizes are as described.  Any ideas why this might happen?

Some side notes that may or may not be relevant:
- I'm using PhoneGap + JQueryMobile, not that that should mapper
- I dragged a reference to the two icons into the Resources/icons folder, replacing the original icon.png and icon@2x.png files.

Comment: Have you deployed your app to the simulator, or any device? If so are the resolutions wrong in iOS?

Comment: Yes, I deployed it to my actual iPhone 4S.  The icon appears normal size, but it is blurry and non-retina.

Comment: This is happening to me as well. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  At some point it fixed itself, however.  I wish I knew what I did.  I didn't rebuild the project or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the icon, as this is png image there was transparent background so crop the png file that starts with postion where blue color starts in the image. This solves your problem

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I double checked and there is no transparent padding around the icon.  The icon does not have transparent rounded corners either.  I wonder if that could be a factor?

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well. I experimented and discovered that it is related to the pixels/inch resolution. icon@2x seems to want 150 pixels/inch for full size, 300 pixels/inch gives half size, and 600 pixels/inch (which is what I was using) gives quarter size. As near as I can tell, image resolution didn't really have that much of an impact on the quality of the image when placed on an iPhone. My icon is very sensitive to rendering, so any degradation of image quality would have been readily noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Changing all the icons to 72dpi from 300dpi solved my problem.

Comment: BTW you can easily change the DPI in Preview app: just tap the Tools/Adjust Size and you'll see the Resolution field.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. My solution was to just open them in Xee (probably lots of other programs will do the trick) and resave them as png. My icons were originally created in gimp and this may something to do with they way that gimp saved them.

Exactly same thing happened to my defaults files - the same solution fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when creating assets with Gimp. To solve it I unchecked "Save resolution" in the export dialog.

[image: Gimp Export Image Dialog]